# How to change ImageField into FileField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a ImageField in one of the models, is there any way to change that field into FileFiled? If converted how can one identify image during upload?

What is the difference between ImageField and FileField in django?

Comment: from the doc, *"Inherits all attributes and methods from `FileField`, but also validates that the uploaded object is a valid image"*

Comment: That means it can be simply changed into FileField and migrated?